# Collect subscribers from Pivot table where from ID of county

Tags: php, laravel

I have a subscribers table containing `name`, `email`, `timestamps`.

I have a counties table containing `ID`, `name`.

I have a pivot table called `county_subscriber` containing `id`, `county_id`, `subscriber_id`.

---

I am trying to write a function to email subscribers where a specific property within the county has been updated.

I am trying to obtain a list of subscribers, I have the property assigned to a variable already.

The property county is available from the update function and is available with `$home->county` which for this example is say `37`

I've tried various queries such as:

and

```
$subs = Subscriber::whereIn('counties', $home->county)->pluck('id')->toArray());
```

but I have not managed to return any due to errors in the code.

There is a belongsToMany relationship setup between the subscriber and the county.

Error received is:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/PHFS/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 915
```

Comment: added to the post

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going via the relationship:

```
$county = County::where('id', $home->county)->first()->subscribers;
```